# In-app purchase entitlement to your app id

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

i am really confused, I dont know how can add In-app purchase to my existing app. When in 'Capabilities' i choose on In-app purchase it show me only error `add the in app purchase entitlement to your app id`. I added app id in dev center and in-app purchase in itunesconnect. My Bundle ID is `sk.freetech.zatracenacestina.intro` and in-app purchase i set up to `sk.freetech.zatracenacestina.intro.package` but I dont know where can I fill it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can follow these tutorial
1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial
2. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_in_app_purchase.htm
3. http://code4app.net/ios/In-App-Purchase/4fc85be56803fa4a49000000

Create a class name it IAPHelper subclass NSObject

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>


UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification;

typedef void (^RequestProductsCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSArray * products);
@protocol inAppPurchaseDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)transactionSucsess:(NSString *)transactionId;
-(void)transactionOnRestore:(NSString *)transactionId;
-(void)transactionOnFail;
@end
@interface IAPHelper : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,readwrite)id<inAppPurchaseDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers;
- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product;
- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier;
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions;



@end
```

in IAPHelper.m

## import "IAPHelper.h"

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification = @"IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification";


@interface IAPHelper () <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
@end


@implementation IAPHelper {
    SKProductsRequest * _productsRequest;
    RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;

    NSSet * _productIdentifiers;
    NSMutableSet * _purchasedProductIdentifiers;
}


- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        // Store product identifiers
        _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

        // Check for previously purchased products
        _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
            BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
            if (productPurchased) {
                [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
                NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            }
        }

        // Add self as transaction observer
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    }
    return self;

}

- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {

    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];
}

- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}

- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    _completionHandler(NO, nil);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionOBserver

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];


    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];


    if(_delegate)
      [_delegate  transactionSucsess:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];


    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];


    if(_delegate)
        [_delegate  transactionOnRestore:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

    if(_delegate)
        [_delegate  transactionOnFail];
}

- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

    [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}

- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

@end
```

Create a class RageIAPHelper subclass of IAPHelper

```
#import "IAPHelper.h"

@interface RageIAPHelper : IAPHelper

+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance;



@end
```

In RageIAPHelper.m

```
#import "RageIAPHelper.h"

@implementation RageIAPHelper

+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static RageIAPHelper * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                      @"your identifier",@"your identifier",
                                      nil];
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];

    });
    return sharedInstance;
}




@end


[[RageIAPHelper  sharedInstance]  setDelegate:(id)self];

[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {


    if (success) {
        totalProduct_Arr =products;
        for (SKProduct *s in totalProduct_Arr) {
            NSLog(@"product Identifier %@",[s productIdentifier]);
            if ([[s productIdentifier]isEqualToString:FULLVERSION]) {
                [self.btnFullVersion setEnabled:YES];
            }
            else if ([[s productIdentifier]isEqualToString:REMOVE_ADS]) {
                [self.btnRemoveAd setEnabled:YES];
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView   *alertFail=[[UIAlertView  alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Product Not Found" message:@"Fails to load product.." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertFail  show];

    }
}];
```

and to buy product

```
                     [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
```

Comment: I followed a lot of tutorials but when they switch on in-app purchase it is working normally for them.

Comment: For example second but it show me only error Invalid product identifier. But I have good ID

Comment: then you change the identifier. do you test in simulator or device?

Comment: I test on device but can you edit your code because it show me some errors this part http://pastebin.com/LDfnnzf6

Comment: you create the class. and after that code whch i written is how you call this class. i have two inapp purchase if i found this product thn enable the button on and off

Comment: So this calling I call from viewDidLoad in my ViewController?

Comment: have they worked for you yet? I found its a issue with my xcode7.. Went to 6.4 re-enabled the in-app purchase via the capabilities tab of xcode6.4 and it worked fine. Opened in xcode7 and it worked fine again. I am unable to make in-app purchase work in xcode7 even if you make custom entitlements file in dev panel it wont work with xcode7 unless you go to 6 re add the entitlements, then and only then it will work in xcode7 - OPSY Just saw its aug 14

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you. Follow this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW7) step by step.

You can use this code also.

1. Add the StoreKit.framework, Accounts.framework, MobileCoreServices.framework, QuartzCore.framework, CFNetwork.framework, SystemConfiguration.framework.
2. In .h file import 'StoreKit.h'
    #import
3. Add these delegate on .h class
4. Declare a property for SKProductsRequest
   @property(nonatomic,strong)SKProductsRequest *request;

Now In .m class copy this code for in-app purchase

```
-(void)startpurching
{
    NSArray *arrPackageproductIdentifier=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Your Product Id",nil];
    NSString *strPrductIdentifier=[arrPackageproductIdentifier objectAtIndex:0];

    request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
          initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject:strPrductIdentifier]];
    NSLog(@"%@",request);
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}


- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;

    if ([myProduct count]==0) {
        UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Cannot connect !! Please check your internet connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alt show];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"pro...%@",[[myProduct objectAtIndex:0] productIdentifier]);

        SKPayment *newPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:[myProduct objectAtIndex:0]];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:newPayment];

    }
}


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"Transaction....%@",transactions);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            NSLog(@"%d",transaction.transactionState);
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"=======%@",transactions);
}

- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    NSLog(@"Transaction Completed");

    NSUserDefaults *remvAddSttr = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // saving an NSString
    NSString *chkRemVal=@"10";
    [remvAddSttr setObject:chkRemVal forKey:@"revAdd"];

    UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Transaction completed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alrt show];
}


- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"Transaction Restored");
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Unsuccessful"
                                                    message:@"Your purchase failed. Please try again."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Now need to design a Restore button for non-consumable product.
For Restore button clicked copy this code.

```
//*****************************************************************************
//*****************************************************************************
-(void)restoreBtnClicked
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
         NSLog(@"error.code");
    }
}

- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    // NSMutableArray* purchasableObjects  = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        NSLog(@"productID...%@",productID);
        if ([productID isEqualToString:@"Your Product Id"]) {
            UIAlertView *alt12=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Product Restored" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alt12 show];
        }
    }
    //Block Call to access the products
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this error appears because of having NO registered device in member center.
Here is the case that help for me.

1. Register device in member center.
2. Set your development team in "Your target" -> General -> "Team"
   After that this error disappear for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but I just had the same issue (I was following a Ray W. tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial)... 
When I added my signing team (Targets > General > Signing > Team) it was resolved. 
This is not mentioned in the tutorial (no slight on Ray W. - they're generally great)